# Julia: Zygote.@adjoint from Enzyme.autodiff

Tags: julia, differentiation

Given the function `f!` below :

```
function f!(s::Vector, a::Vector, b::Vector)
  
  s .= a .+ b
  return nothing

end # f!
```

How can I define an adjoint for **Zygote** based on

`Enzyme.autodiff(f!, Const, Duplicated(s, dz_ds). Duplicated(a, zero(a)), Duplicated(b, zero(b)))` ?

```
Zygote.@adjoint f!(s, a, b) = f!(s, a, b), # What would come here ?
```

Comment: I'd _really_ recomment to ask this kind of specialized question on the #autodiff channel of the Julia Slack. All the people writing those libraries frequent it, and much more than SO, I guess.

Comment: Thanks @phipsgabler, I'll be sharing a solution I could find. But next time I'll ask it on the Julia Slack channels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could figure out a way, sharing it here.

For a given function `foo`, `Zygote.pullback(foo, args...)` returns `foo(args...)` and the backward pass (which allows for gradients computations).

My goal is to tell `Zygote` to use `Enzyme` for the backward pass.

This can be done by means of `Zygote.@adjoint` (see more [here](https://fluxml.ai/Zygote.jl/latest/adjoints/#Custom-Adjoints-2)).

In case of array-valued functions, `Enzyme` requires a mutating version that returns `nothing` and its result to be in `args` (see more [here](https://enzyme.mit.edu/julia/pullbacks/)).

The function `f!` in the question post is an `Enzyme`-compatible version of a sum of two arrays.

Since `f!` returns `nothing`, `Zygote` would simply return `nothing`
when the backward pass is called on some gradient passed to us.

A solution is to place `f!` inside a wrapper (say `f`) that returns the array `s`

and to define `Zygote.@adjoint` for `f`, rather than `f!`.

Hence,

```
function f(a::Vector, b::Vector)

  s = zero(a)
  f!(s, a, b)
  return s

end
```

```
function enzyme_back(dzds, a, b)

  s    = zero(a)
  dzda = zero(dzds)
  dzdb = zero(dzds)
  Enzyme.autodiff(
    f!,
    Const,
    Duplicated(s, dzds),
    Duplicated(a, dzda),
    Duplicated(b, dzdb)
  )
  return (dzda, dzdb)

end
```

and

```
Zygote.@adjoint f(a, b) = f(a, b), dzds -> enzyme_back(dzds, a, b)
```

inform `Zygote` to use `Enzyme` in the backward pass.

---

Finally, you can check that calling `Zygote.gradient` either on

```
g1(a::Vector, b::Vector) = sum(abs2, a + b)
```

or

```
g2(a::Vector, b::Vector) = sum(abs2, f(a, b))
```

yields the same results.

Comment: The only issue is that the Enzyme will execute the forward pass "again". Ideally we would use the split ABI, which hasn't been given a public API in Enzyme.jl just yet.